# Python API KeyError

Tags: python

I'm new to both python and APIs. lol. But google isn't helping. I have the below simple authentication request and am getting a `KeyError: 'token'`  from the line, `authorization = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token['token']}`

I appreciate any guidance you can provide!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import argparse
import math
import os
import json


export_format_map = {
    "csv": "zip",
    "json": "json",
    "kml": "kml"
    }

def download_logs(args):
    """
    NOTE: Requires user credentials
    Downloads log files from user-specified host in user-specified file format.
    """
    rest_api = "https://address.here/api/1.0"
    
    # Step 1. Login and get token to authenticate requests
    print(f"Logging into {rest_api}...")
    
    # Get username and password from environment variables
    username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
    password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
    
    # Put the credentials into a dictionary object
    credentials = {"email": username, "password": password}

    r = requests.post(f"{rest_api}/authentication/login", json=credentials)
    
    # Build the JWT compliant authorization dictionary
    token = json.loads(r.text)
    authorization = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token['token']}

 # Step 2. Gather a list of contacts filtered to be within the min/max timestamps
    def get_agents(params):
        """Sends GET request to API with provided parameters; Returns response."""
        response = requests.get(
            url=f"{rest_api}/agent",
            params=params,
            headers=authorization
        ).json()
        return response
   #code continues.....
```

I have also tried setting up the token request like this with the same error:

```
TOKEN = requests.post(
        url=f"{rest_api}/authentication/login",
        data={
            "email": input("\nusername/email: "),
            "password": getpass.getpass(),
        }
    ).json()

authorization = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN['token']}
```

Comment: Try printing out the raw JSON in `r.text` to see what you are getting. It looks like there is no field named `token` in the response.

Comment: You're getting `token` via `token = json.loads(r.text)`, but obviously whatever's in `token` doesn't have a field called `token`. What's actually in the object? Why do you think a `token` field should be there?

Comment: well, normally the response would be ```{token: 'string'}```. Printing r,text def was a big help. lol. I'm getting a statusCode 400: 'bad request'. Should have checked that. lol.